# how to remove delimiter and extra spaces in pyspark write option

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am doing a extract from a table in dataframe and calling python udf on few columns( the udf is to give the ebcdic value ). Once i write the file as text mode. I do see extra columns which added at after every record which are not constant. one is line delimiter which is \n and other are spaces which varies for records.

Is there a way to strict the length of the fields to be written and also without the delimiter.

Comment: Please share an example input and the code you tried and expected output

Comment: Try to add a Schema for your data when creating the dataframe ?